# How to check if authority exists in a collection of GrantedAuthority?

Tags: java, spring, spring-security

```
Authentication auth = SecurityContextHolder.getContext().getAuthentication();
Collection<? extends GrantedAuthority> roles = auth.getAuthorities();
```

How can I check if `roles` contains a specific authority like `"ROLE_ADMIN"`?

Comment: What version of Spring Security do you use? What `GrantedAuthority` implementation do you use?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I don't know of any built-in function, but here is a utility method you could use.

```
if (userHasAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN")) { ... }
```

.

```
public static boolean userHasAuthority(String authority)
{
    List<GrantedAuthority> authorities = getUserAuthorities();

    for (GrantedAuthority grantedAuthority : authorities) {
        if (authority.equals(grantedAuthority.getAuthority())) {
            return true;
        }
    }

    return false;
}
```

Answer (score 8):

Robert's answer is correct if you don't know the implementation of the `GrantedAuthority` in the list, as is this:

```
auth.getAuthorities().stream().anyMatch(ga -> ga.getAuthority().equals("ROLE_ADMIN"))
```

If however, you know they'll all be `SimpleGrantedAuthority`, then you can do this:

```
auth.getAuthorities().contains(new SimpleGrantedAuthority("ROLE_ADMIN"))
```